# How can I trigger jQuery fadeIn() fadeOut() from a <div> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a hidden element on the page: `<div id="hidden"></div>`

I have another element on the page that I want to be a button trigger: `<div id="trigger"></div>`

I want to do something like this:

```
$('#trigger').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'clicked') {
        $('#hidden').fadeIn(700);
        $('#trigger').fadeOut(250);         
    }
});
```

Do I have to do something to the `trigger` element in css and how do I listen for that event of clicking `trigger`?

Comment: `if($(this).val() == 'clicked')` Do you expect this to be standard behaviour? Or are you setting this value with a different piece of javascript you aren't showing? If you aren't setting this value, then just remove the if statement all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element div doesn't have attribute *value*, so you don't need

```
   if($(this).val() == 'clicked')
```

condition. That's all and now your code will work.

Comment: Thank you, do I need to set my css for that element to allow it to be clickable?

Comment: @SpringheeledJack No need for CSS to make it clickable, your jQuery does that. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/mnn0a5as/1/

Comment: @SpringheeledJack No, you don't.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements are already inside the DOM you can do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#trigger').click(function(){
        $('#hidden').fadeIn(700);
        $('#trigger').fadeOut(250);
    });
});
```

if the elements are not in the DOM on page load:

```
$('#trigger').on('click', function(){
    $('#hidden').fadeIn(700);
    $('#trigger').fadeOut(250);  
});
```